# Arangodb Docker Container: Could not connect to endpoint 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8529', database: '_system', username: 'root' docker

Tags: docker, arangodb

I've installed `ArangoDb` in Ubuntu 20.04 through `docker`, and started an instance:

```
raphy@pc:~$ sudo docker run -e ARANGO_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=1 -d --name arangodb-instance arangodb/arangodb
ca6c80f7895c1e6b379937c8b2e71a3d0134ab0d39b09b87ecd2a0feb55b53e4
raphy@pc:~$ sudo docker run -e ARANGO_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=1 --name playground --link arangodb-instance:db-link arangodb/arangodb
===========================================
GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: Uyi2Su3XNQggybWR
===========================================
Initializing root user...Hang on...
2022-07-04T16:34:01Z [9] INFO [f6e0e] {aql} memory limit per AQL query automatically set to 20163799449 bytes. to modify this value, please adjust the startup option `--query.memory-limit`
2022-07-04T16:34:01Z [9] INFO [a1c60] {syscall} file-descriptors (nofiles) hard limit is 1048576, soft limit is 1048576
2022-07-04T16:34:02Z [9] INFO [c1b63] {arangosearch} ArangoSearch maintenance: [1..1] commit thread(s), [1..1] consolidation thread(s)
2022-07-04T16:34:02Z [9] INFO [7da27] {startup} server will now shut down due to upgrade, database initialization or admin restoration.
Initializing database...Hang on...
Database initialized...Starting System...
2022-07-04T16:34:06Z [1] INFO [e52b0] {general} ArangoDB 3.9.2 [linux] 64bit, using jemalloc, build tags/v3.9.2-0-g8bf70c5f5b6, VPack 0.1.35, RocksDB 6.27.0, ICU 64.2, V8 7.9.317, OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022
2022-07-04T16:34:06Z [1] INFO [75ddc] {general} detected operating system: Linux version 5.13.0-52-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-067) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #59~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 16 21:21:28 UTC 2022
2022-07-04T16:34:06Z [1] INFO [25362] {memory} Available physical memory: 33606332416 bytes, available cores: 8
2022-07-04T16:34:06Z [1] INFO [3bb7d] {cluster} Starting up with role SINGLE
2022-07-04T16:34:06Z [1] INFO [f6e0e] {aql} memory limit per AQL query automatically set to 20163799449 bytes. to modify this value, please adjust the startup option `--query.memory-limit`
2022-07-04T16:34:06Z [1] INFO [a1c60] {syscall} file-descriptors (nofiles) hard limit is 1048576, soft limit is 1048576
2022-07-04T16:34:06Z [1] INFO [fe333] {engines} RocksDB recovery starting, scanning WAL starting from sequence number 94, latest sequence number: 205
2022-07-04T16:34:06Z [1] INFO [a4ec8] {engines} RocksDB recovery finished, WAL entries scanned: 115, recovery start sequence number: 94, latest WAL sequence number: 205, max tick value found in WAL: 116, last HLC value found in WAL: 1737440567212638208
2022-07-04T16:34:06Z [1] INFO [c1b63] {arangosearch} ArangoSearch maintenance: [1..1] commit thread(s), [1..1] consolidation thread(s)
2022-07-04T16:34:06Z [1] INFO [6ea38] {general} using endpoint 'http+tcp://0.0.0.0:8529' for non-encrypted requests
2022-07-04T16:34:07Z [1] INFO [cf3f4] {general} ArangoDB (version 3.9.2 [linux]) is ready for business. Have fun!
```

Now, I want to use `ArangoShell`:

I opened another console

```
raphy@pc:~$ sudo docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS      NAMES
608013c29220   arangodb/arangodb   "/entrypoint.sh aran…"   33 minutes ago   Up 33 minutes   8529/tcp   playground
ca6c80f7895c   arangodb/arangodb   "/entrypoint.sh aran…"   34 minutes ago   Up 34 minutes   8529/tcp   arangodb-instance
```

But , trying to follow these indications: https://hub.docker.com/r/arangodb/arangodb/

I get this error:

`Could not connect to endpoint 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8529', database: '_system', username: 'root'`

```
raphy@pc:~$ sudo docker exec playground arangosh

                                       _     
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __   __ _  ___  ___| |__  
 / _` | '__/ _` | '_ \ / _` |/ _ \/ __| '_ \ 
| (_| | | | (_| | | | | (_| | (_) \__ \ | | |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_| |_|\__, |\___/|___/_| |_|
                       |___/                 

arangosh (ArangoDB 3.9.2 [linux] 64bit, using jemalloc, build tags/v3.9.2-0-g8bf70c5f5b6, VPack 0.1.35, RocksDB 6.27.0, ICU 64.2, V8 7.9.317, OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022)
Copyright (c) ArangoDB GmbH

Command-line history will be persisted when the shell is exited. You can use `--console.history false` to turn this off
Could not connect to endpoint 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8529', database: '_system', username: 'root'
Error message: 'not authorized to execute this request'


Uf wiederluege! 再见！ Na shledanou! Auf Wiedersehen! Bye Bye! Adiau! ¡Hasta luego! Εις το επανιδείν! ءاقللا ىلإ
להתראות! Arrivederci! Tot ziens! Adjö! Au revoir! さようなら До свидания! Até Breve! خداحافظ! Uz redzēšanos! შეხვედრამდე 안녕히 가세요! Sampai jumpa!
raphy@pc:~$
```

How to connect to `arangosh` to an instance of an `arangodb container` ?

Answer (score 1):

In this way it seems working fine:

```
raphy@pc:~$ sudo docker run -e ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypwd -p 8529:8529 -d --name arangodb-instance arangodb/arangodb
10fea7fd22ff14e6e2c773adaedb79df4698d25e2b57fb35ae896988d495f298
raphy@pc:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
10fea7fd22ff   arangodb/arangodb   "/entrypoint.sh aran…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:8529->8529/tcp, :::8529->8529/tcp   arangodb-instance
raphy@pc:~$ sudo docker exec -it arangodb-instance arangosh
Please specify a password: 

                                       _     
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __   __ _  ___  ___| |__  
 / _` | '__/ _` | '_ \ / _` |/ _ \/ __| '_ \ 
| (_| | | | (_| | | | | (_| | (_) \__ \ | | |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_| |_|\__, |\___/|___/_| |_|
                       |___/                 

arangosh (ArangoDB 3.9.2 [linux] 64bit, using jemalloc, build tags/v3.9.2-0-g8bf70c5f5b6, VPack 0.1.35, RocksDB 6.27.0, ICU 64.2, V8 7.9.317, OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022)
Copyright (c) ArangoDB GmbH

Command-line history will be persisted when the shell is exited. You can use `--console.history false` to turn this off
Connected to ArangoDB 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529, version: 3.9.2 [SINGLE, server], database: '_system', username: 'root'

Type 'tutorial' for a tutorial or 'help' to see common examples
127.0.0.1:8529@_system>
```